# Why does Hazelcast drag performance although when not running?

Tags: java, performance, distributed-computing, hazelcast

Hazelcast seems not to fully shutdown. At least that's what my performance analysis is saying. If i execute the code below (the hazelcast instance formed a cluster with exactly one other node on a different vm in the same network) it's constantly 10-20% slower than executing the code without creating a hazelcast instance. What really makes me wonder is the performance loss albeit a prior shutdown of the hazelcast instance.

```
HazelcastInstance hi = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance()
hi.shutdown
... code goes here ...
```

Answer (score 2):

There should be no such difference.

Do you exclude the Hazelcast instance creation and disposal (shutdown) from your measurements?

Following JMH Microbenchmark gives me similar numbers in both cases - when the  Hazelcast is created+destroyed and when it's omitted completely:

```java
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public static class ExecutionPlan {

    @Setup(Level.Trial)
    public void setUp() {
        Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance().shutdown();
    }
}


@Benchmark
public static void test(ExecutionPlan plan, Blackhole bh) throws Exception {
    long[] numbers = new long[2<<20];
    for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        byte[] bytes = Long.toString(numbers[i]).getBytes("UTF-8");
        bh.consume(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(bytes));
    }
}
```

If you still experience the performance decrease, share your code which reproduces the problem, please.